# Writing to file using list comprehension with two different pieces of code

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I have two pieces of code that I thought were equivalent; can anyone explain the rationale I'm missing regarding list comprehension?

The following code, when written to a file, produces only the contents of the last subfolder:

```
for root, directories, files in os.walk(directory):
    filenames = [os.path.join(root, filename) for filename in files]
```

The code that follows, however, does exactly what I want (writes all the contents of the root directory and its subdirectories):

```
allfiles = [os.path.join(root,f) for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory) for f in files]
```

So, they seem *identical* to me, but they obviously aren't. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you are *not* writing to a file using a list comprehension. You are using list comprehensions to build lists of full filepaths instead.

The first list comprehension is applied *per directory* found by the `os.walk()` method. Depending on how many directories there are below the main `directory` path, it'll be called several times.

The second list comprehension is applied for *all* directories and files. It'll be called only once, and build a list of all files in the whole of the  `directory` file system structure.

If you wanted the first to give the same result, you'd need to extend a list object:

```
all_files = [] 
for root, directories, files in os.walk(directory):
    filenames = [os.path.join(root, filename) for filename in files]
    all_files.extend(filenames)
```

Now you are not discarding all but the last result of that list comprehension.

Comment: So, turns out I forgot I was working in a loop (I'm used to actually calling numbers). And I am *eventually* writing the lists filepaths to a file - I just didn't add that code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the first code `filenames` is reset every time as you keep assigning to it. After the loop it only contains the value from the last iteration through the loop.

In the second code you end up with the results from all values that are produced by `os.walk(directory)`.

Answer (score 1):

In your first loop:

```
for root, directories, files in os.walk(directory):
    filenames = [os.path.join(root, filename) for filename in files]
```

You are re-assigning `filenames` to a new list comprehension each iteration of the loop. This is resulting in `filenames` being only the list-comprehension of the last directory from `os.walk()`.

You want to change it to something like:

```
filenames = []
for root, directories, files in os.walk(directory):
    filenames.extend(os.path.join(root, filename) for filename in files)
```

Comment: We posted the same answer, so I think you are pretty smart! :)